# How to reload page in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, local-storage

I need to reload a page in the ionic app.

I am using `{reload:true}` methods, but does not work for me.

So any one give an idea to solve this problem? And also how to remove `localstorage` item value in ionic?

Comment: $route.reload(), and may be localStorage.remove('key')

Comment: sorry, code missing

Comment: `localstorage.remove(key)` will remove data stored with that `key`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$window.location.reload();
```

You use `$route.reload()` to reload a route.

If you are using `$stateProvider`, then try:

```
$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
```

Comment: i tried above all methods,but it's not working.give any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having problem re initializing controller in ionic. Instead of reloading your page in ionic. I prefer you use the following:

```
angular.module('nameYouSPecify').controller('your controllername',function($scope){
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function(){ 
//keep all your codes inside here
});

})
```

If you are really in need of page reload.Ionic uses `$stateProvider`. So, to reload use the following:

```
angular.module('nameYouSPecify').controller('your controllername',function($scope,$state){
     $state.go('StateName',{},{reload:true});
    //the middle blank is filled with stateparams if you have any  
});
```

To remove **localStorage**:  `$window.localStorage.clear();`.Inject `$window` in controller.

To remove **$localStorage**: `$localStorage.$reset();`.You need `ngStorage` and need to inject `$localStorage` in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your controller.js

```
$state.go($state.current, $stateParams, {reload: true, inherit: false});
```

also make sure you set cache to false in app.js